# pChart timeline with gaps

Tags: php, mysql, pchart

I want to use pChart to render a simple line graph of a sample value vs. the date.  I have the basics working, but how do I handle gaps in the date?  The samples are already averaged by the quarter year, but not every quarter has a sample.  Sometimes it skips a quarter or two.

Currently, these gaps are compressed on the X axis one after another, instead of being spaced out in their natural order in a number line.

The data is coming from a MySQL database.  I'm probably missing something simple.  Can anyone help?

```
#Array variables.
$date       = "";
$value      = "";

#Fetch the database rows, and sort them into arrays.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $date[] = $row["date"];
    $value[]    = $row["value"];
}

#Create a chart data object.
$MyData = new pData();

#Pass the data to the chart.
$MyData->addPoints($date, "Date");
$MyData->addPoints($value, "Value");

#Configure labels.
$MyData->setAxisName(0,"Value");

#Set the date as the X axis.
$MyData->setAbscissa("Date");
$MyData->setAbscissaName("Date");
```

Comment: This might depend on your MSQL Query - is this because 'value' might return NULL for instance? In that case, you can use pChart's `VOID` keyword to polyfill empty values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trying to use the `drawLineChart()` function, when it should be using the `drawScatterLineChart()` function.  The differences aren't very well explained, but are crucial.

A "Line Chart" doesn't use a number line for its independent axis.  It's used for charts with a non-numerical axis, like months of the year.  This axis doesn't register gaps like a natural number line would, because text doesn't necessarily have values which can be ordered in a logical way.

The "Scatter Line Chart" is a normal XY chart with proper number lines on its axes.  It responds to gaps in values like one would expect.  This should really be the default example in the documentation.